# Flutter: Text clipping not working when in a Row

Tags: text, layout, flutter, row

I have a situation where there are two text items in a row. The first text can have a variable length, but I don't want to wrap the texts in two lines. So I need the first text to be clipped when the parent does not have enough width for it and the second text. Now, if I do not place the texts in a row, it works as expected. But if they are in a Row, the clipping does not occur. I can not wrap the first text in an Expanded widget (which fixes the clipping problem) because it adds a blank space between the two texts.
Here is a code snippet

```
Container(
         child: Row (
            children: <Widget>[
               Text("Long text that needs to be clipped",
                  overflow: TextOverflow.clip,
                  textAlign: TextAlign.left),
                  //there should be no blank space between the elements
                  Text( "+1",
                      textAlign: TextAlign.left,
                      overflow: TextOverflow.fade),
                ],
              )
          )
```

[image]

Been scratching my head for a while...

Comment: what happens if you set the width of the container or place the text widget inside another container?

Comment: Adding width to the parent container gives an overflow error. Wrapping the text in a container with width fixes the clipping issue but I need the second element to shift to the right until there is no space left, then I need the text to clip. I have added a screen shot to the question to better illustrate the problem.

Comment: On your row try adding 'mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,' and 'crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,' one of these might help

Comment: Thanks for the response man, but that didn't work.

Comment: :( Is the overflow error always a fixed number no matter how long the text is? If it is, a quick hack might to just use MediaQuery to get the width then minus the overflow.

Comment: Did you try `Expanded` with `flex` property? Wrap both `Text` Widget in `Expanded` Widget and give `flex` as 2 for the first one and 1 for the second `Expanded` Widget.

Answer (score 3):

We can use `Expanded` as per below:

```
Material(
      child: Container(
          color: appColor,
          child: Row(
            children: <Widget>[
              Expanded(
                child: Align(
                  alignment: AlignmentDirectional.centerStart,
                  child: Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 8.0),
                    child: Text(
                      "Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.",
                      softWrap: false,
                      overflow: TextOverflow.fade,
                      style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              IconButton(
                icon: Image.asset('assets/images/filter.png'),
                onPressed: () {},
              ),
              IconButton(
                icon: Image.asset('assets/images/notification.png'),
                onPressed: () {},
              ),
            ],
          )),
    );
```